# Having trouble with creating topGO object in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, ontology, rna-seq

When putting all of the arguments into the topGO object, I get the following error.

```
myGOdata <- new("topGOdata",
                description = "My Project",
                ontology = "MF",  
                allGenes = geneList,
                annot =  annFUN.gene2GO, 
                gene2GO = geneID2GO)

Building most specific GOs .....
    ( 0 GO terms found. )

Build GO DAG topology ..........
    ( 0 GO terms and 0 relations. )
Nothing to do:
Error in split.default(names(sort(nl)), f.index) : 
  first argument must be a vector
```

The geneList is a named vector consisting of a list of genes with genes of interest defined by either 0 or 1.

```
GeneNames <- names(geneID2GO) # get full list of genes
myInterestingGenes <- sample(D4D1new$Geneid) # get list of genes of interest (D4D1new is from a DESeq2 object)
geneList <- factor(as.integer(GeneNames %in% myInterestingGenes))
names(geneList) <- GeneNames
str(geneList)
#  Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4837] "A0001" "A0002" "A0004" "A0005" ...
head(geneList)
# A0001 A0002 A0004 A0005 A0006 A0008 
#     0     0     0     0     0     1 
# Levels: 0 1
```

The GO terms are made up from the geneID2GO object. GO_id.txt containes the list of genes and the GO terms, speerated by a tab.

```
geneID2GO <- readMappings("GO_id.txt")
head(geneID2GO)
# $A0001
# [1] "GO:0005634;"
# 
# $A0002
# [1] "GO:0015991;GO:0033180;GO:0015078;"
# 
# $A0004
# [1] "GO:0006807;GO:0016810;"
# 
# $A0005
# [1] "GO:0006388;GO:0000213;"
# 
# $A0006
# [1] "GO:0016021;GO:0055085;"
# 
# $A0008
# [1] # "GO:0004672;GO:0016020;GO:0005524;GO:0016773;GO:0006468;GO:0008537;"
```

As far as I can tell, I've set up the arguments and objects correctly. It seems like it can't see the GO terms but I think I've inputted them as described in the vignette. Not sure why it wants the first argument to be a vector, as the geneList is a named vector, or I've misunderstood something.

I'm new to posting on here and I'm still learning with r so if I've ommitted something important or people want more details let me know and I'll update. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your GO_id.txt is not properly formatted, there are ";" in the GO terms and the GO terms are not separated. Have a look at system.file("examples/geneid2go.map", package = "topGO") to see how your file should be formatted

Comment: @Basti You are correct., the file was formatted incorrectly. Many thanks!